# State defaults to undefined whenever switching input fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to setup a payment gateway but i first want to store all of the billing details in state variables to then pass to the gateway, but in the input fields whenever i type the email address it will output it fine as long as im still inside the input field, but when i select the first_name field its like the state doesnt save and it defaults back to undefined, i feel like im missing something here?

Current states:

```
let [billingInfo, setBillingInfo] = useState({
    email: "",
    first_name: "",
    last_name: "",
    company_name: "",
    address: "",
    extra_address: "",
    city: "",
    country: "",
    state: "",
    zip_code: "",
  });
```

How I output to console:

```
const testM = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(billingInfo.email);
    console.log(billingInfo.first_name);
    console.log(billingInfo.last_name);
  }
```

Handle input method:

```
let handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setBillingInfo({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
```

Example of input fields:

```
<form className="mt-4 ">
            <h4 className="mt-4">Contact Information</h4>
            <div className=" mb-3" style={{ height: "3rem" }}>
              <input
                type="tel"
                name="email"
                value={state.email}
                className="rounded"
                style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
                placeholder=" Email Address.."
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
            </div>
            <h4 className="mt-4">Shipping Information</h4>
            <div className="row" style={{ height: "3.5rem" }}>
              <div className="mb-3 col-6">
                <input
                  type="tel"
                  name="first_name"
                  value={state.first_name}
                  className="rounded"
                  style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
                  placeholder=" First Name.."
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="mb-3 col-6" style={{ height: "3.5rem" }}>
                <input
                  type="tel"
                  name="last_name"
                  value={state.last_name}
                  className="rounded"
                  style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
                  placeholder=" Last Name.."
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                />
              </div>
```

and onClick that outputs the state in console:

```
<div className="row justify-content-center">
                {/* <StripeCheckout stripeKey="pk_test_51H7BSCCazjyRa53uXCJ5565vod7VjMPLAGF2IADL748jGZdsFYkp11PlMVAPVyjLiIMW5OL1VS1RN5mBXMgqCwiM00YjxfJ0B0" token="" name="Buy React" amount=""> */}
                  <button className="btn" onClick={testM}>
                    Pay Now
                  </button>
                {/* </StripeCheckout> */}
              </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be that when you are updating your state via `setBillingInfo({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })`, you are actually replacing your initial `billingInfo` object with another object that contains only one key?

I'd try updating it like `setBillingInfo({ ...billingInfo, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })` and see if that solves your issue.

Comment: Woah that must have been it, what does ... even do? Thats a very useful skill to use it appears.

Comment: Oh sorry, I should've properly explained. `...` is called "spread syntax". It takes an array or object and expands the content of it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax So what you are doing there is you are creating a new object by first taking everything inside your current state object (via spreading), and then finally, updating/replacing the key you want to update (`[e.target.name]: e.target.value` will rewrite the relevant key).

Comment: Ahhhh that makes so much more sense, i appreciate your help and detailed explanation!!!

Comment: Glad to be of help :) Also, something worth noting: You need to first spread your current object, then update your key, or else the old value of the key would rewrite the new value and it wouldn't work. So the order matters.